# Indicate the C++ app to look for dynamic libraries into the ./lib subfolder at runtime

Tags: c++, runtime, shared-libraries, subdirectory

Probably a newbie's question for those used to package and distribute applications:

when launching my executable on a different computer than the one used for compilation, I need to place several dynamic libraries in the same folder to run it.

I want the executable to look at runtime in a relative lib/ subfolder placed besides it and where I would have placed all these libraries.  What do I have to do for this?

Comment: what environment? You should be able to do this on UNIX and windows by adding the directory to your `PATH` envar.

Comment: I don't want to request final users to do such manipulation (will you ask your grandparents to do that? ;-) and I want to avoid modifying the user PATH by adding an absolute path through an installer/program/script, knowing the subfolder is besides the executable.

Comment: the answer is different for windows, mac, and linux. Which one are you developing for?

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong but can't you use makefile and set the library paths using `-L` to the appropriate paths in the adjacent subdirectory.

Comment: @MemyselfandI He's talking about shared libraries, not statically linked libraries.

Comment: @Red Alert - for all of them (WinXP, Win7-32, Linux32, Linux64, OSX), so all the libs I use are cross-platform.

Comment: @Me myself and I - I had a look at this option before posting my question, but not sure it works for shared-libraries and have to dig further to see how to translate it in a CMakeLists.txt

Comment: you can use the `dlopen()` command in unix or `LoadLibrary()` in windows to specify a relative path.

Comment: @RedAlert - Looks like something usable :)  I will try this tomorrow. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Win and MacOS, but for Linux, the good solution would be to set the RPATH binary header of the executable during build-time.

For me [this article](http://blog.tremily.us/posts/rpath/) helped a lot to understand the various ways dynamic libraries are looked up.

How to set the RPATH properly depends on your build system, but basically you need to specify  the option `-rpath=/path/to/lib/folder` for the linker - this will have the effect that the specified path will always be searched first for shared libraries.

To check if your program was linked correctly, you can use

```
readelf --dynamic [executable or shared library] | grep PATH
```

It would be also possible to use the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable, or edit `/etc/ld.so.conf` to set the path where the libraries are located, but these would require changes on the system where the program is run.